# Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint Library

Tags: 2016, enterprise

I know how to implement cascading dropdowns in a sharepoint list. However, I am having difficulty with my library. Should I add this code to Upload.aspx form or the Editform.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom edit form via SharePoint Designer and utilize SP Services Cascading Dropdown script. Ensure you add your JS inside the asp:content tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to do this and the following link illustrate the steps:
http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Hi, Mohamed. This is partially correct. This is applicable to Lists, not libraries. The lists function slightly different. To add Cascading Dropdown to libraries, the user should create a custom edit form through SharePoint Designer and then add the script between the <asp:content> tags for it to work properly.